# One jquery function for several DIVs

Tags: jquery, css

I wrote this jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#change1").hover(function () {
        $(this).find("#changeHeader1").stop().animate( { marginTop: "30px" }, 400 );
        $(this).find("#changeText1").stop().fadeIn(1200);               
        $(this).find("#changeButton1").stop().fadeIn(1200);
    }, function() {
        $(this).find("#changeHeader1").stop().animate( { marginTop: "118px" }, 1000 );                
        $(this).find("#changeText1").stop().fadeOut(700);
        $(this).find("#changeButton1").stop().fadeOut(400);
    });
});
```

It works fine with the first DIV, but doesn't work with the second, thrid ...

Can someone help me with this please?

Thanks and best regards

Martin

Comment: Can you post also the html? What this script is supposed to do?

Comment: __Identifiers in HTML must be unique__ This is expected behavior

Comment: It would be a lot easier for people to debug your code if you could set up a little demo on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Can you Post html ? so that I can work and get you with solution

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` instead of `id`. You cannot use same id for different elements.

Then use the following.

```
$(".change1").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".changeHeader1").stop().animate( { marginTop: "30px" }, 400 );
    $(this).find(".changeText1").stop().fadeIn(1200);               
    $(this).find(".changeButton1").stop().fadeIn(1200);
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".changeHeader1").stop().animate( { marginTop: "118px" }, 1000 );                
    $(this).find(".changeText1").stop().fadeOut(700);
    $(this).find(".changeButton1").stop().fadeOut(400);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use class instead and add the hover function to each of the button.

[Hover animation with multiple elements](http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/BjEEGj)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".change1, .change2, .change3").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".changeHeader1").stop().animate( { marginTop: "30px" }, 400 );
    $(this).find(".changeText1").stop().fadeIn(1200);               
    $(this).find(".changeButton1").stop().fadeIn(1200);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find(".changeHeader1").stop().animate( { marginTop: "118px" }, 1000 );                
    $(this).find(".changeText1").stop().fadeOut(700);
    $(this).find(".changeButton1").stop().fadeOut(400);
 });
});
```

If you want to stick to single class name, yes you can!!

[Hover animation with multiple elements, using single class name](http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/RrOOzw)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".change").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".changeHeader1").stop().animate( { marginTop: "30px" }, 400 );
    $(this).find(".changeText1").stop().fadeIn(1200);               
    $(this).find(".changeButton1").stop().fadeIn(1200);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find(".changeHeader1").stop().animate( { marginTop: "118px" }, 1000 );                
    $(this).find(".changeText1").stop().fadeOut(700);
    $(this).find(".changeButton1").stop().fadeOut(400);
 });
});
```